# Change text of UILabel from outside of function

Tags: ios, swift

Once my UIButton is pressed, I want to change the text of my UILabels. Right now when the button is pressed it transitions to a new ViewController with the same background and same theme, just with different text. I figure it is not the best approach. I cannot access my UILables outside of my function setUpView(). What is the best approach to do this.

```
  @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton){

       //this is where I will change my text. myLabel.text = "new text"
       let modalViewController = PageTwoViewController()
              modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
              present(modalViewController, animated: false)


       }
 func setUpView(){


           let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 235, green: 248, blue: 242)
           view.addSubview(headerView)
        headerView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 150, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 150, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 0)


              let myLabel = UILabel()
            myLabel.text = "Rate your xxxxx"
    myLabel.textColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 0, green: 48, blue: 51)
              myLabel.textAlignment = .left
        myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
headerView.addSubview(myLabel)
                    myLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 32)
              myLabel.anchor(top: headerView.topAnchor, left: headerView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: headerView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 150, paddingLeft: 30, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 40, width: 0, height: 0)

           let steps = UILabel()
                steps.text = "1 of 3"
    steps.textColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 0, green: 48, blue: 51)
    headerView.addSubview(steps)
                        steps.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)

    headerView.addSubview(steps)
    steps.anchor(top: nil, left: headerView.leftAnchor, bottom: myLabel.topAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 30, paddingBottom: 10, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)


        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
                  button.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
                  button.layer.cornerRadius = 30
                  button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                  button.setTitleColor(UIColor.rgb(red: 0, green: 48, blue: 51), for: .normal)
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1.7
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                  button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
                  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        headerView.addSubview(button)
        button.anchor(top: nil, left: headerView.leftAnchor, bottom: headerView.bottomAnchor, right: headerView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 25, paddingBottom: 30, paddingRight: 25, width: 0, height: 60)


    }


override func viewDidLoad() {

    setUpView()
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Comment: You can declare labels as globally in view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the variables globally and then change the text.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {


private var myButton : UIButton = {

  let button = UIButton()
  button.backgroundColor = .red
  return button

}()

private var myLabel: UILabel = {

   let label = UILabel()
   return label

 }()

func setupView() {

  myButton.setTitle("My Button", .normal) //You can do it like this 
  myLabel.text = "This is my text"

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your labels globally in your view controller and then you can use any where in view controller as follow:

```
let myLabel: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()
        return label

    }()
```